# Error with unhashable type while using TweetTokenize

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

I start by downloading some tweets from Twitter.

> `tweet_text = DonaldTrump["Tweets"]
>      tweet_text = tweet_text.str.lower()`

[image]

Then in next step, we move with TweetTokenizer.

`Tweet_tkn = TweetTokenizer()
   tokens = [Tweet_tkn.tokenize(t) for t in tweet_text]
   tokens[0:3]`
[image: first three tokens]

Can someone explain to me and help me solve it.

I have been through similar questions that face similar errors but they provide different solutions.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable and can therefore not be used as `dict` keys.  Otherwise, the program could add a list to a dictionary, change its value, and it is now unclear whether the value in the dictionary should be available under the new or the old list value, or neither.

If you want to use structured data as keys, you need to convert them to immutable types first, such as `tuple` or `frozenset`.  For non-nested objects, you can simply use `tuple(obj)`.  For a simple list of lits, you can use this:

```
tuple(tuple(elem) for elem in obj)
```

But for an arbitrary structure, you will have to use recursion.

Comment: I take this code from an example where he used  a basic script and apply the same code. In his case it works.